# Unit testing RestController that does return a strongly typed object not within a ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, assert, spring-restcontroller

I have the following example of controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pickcard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Card pickCard(@RequestParam String name) {
        return _deckManager.pickCardForPlayer(name);
    }
```

as you can see this endpoint returns a Card not incapsulated in a response entity, but I still would like to assess that the result of the endpoint is successfull, for example a 200.
In my unit test I cannot say that:

```
var response = deckController.pickCard("Test");
assertThat(response.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(200);
```

because indeed the response is not of type ResponseEntity. How can I do this assertion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no point of testing that. It's a unit test. It tests your code. Spring guarantees that the response status will be 200. It has been tested already. If you really want to test the response, you'll need an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you! Makes sense.. in practice I have to test the response status only when there is the chance to return something else than 200.. and in that case I will use the ResponseEntity as returned type from the controller, which will allow me to test it. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, there is a pretty big chance that Spring will return something else than 200. For example if you mess up something with the @RequestMapping (content type etc.). But indeed, for testing it you need an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @JBNizet in the comments:

"here is no point of testing that. It's a unit test. It tests your code. Spring guarantees that the response status will be 200. It has been tested already. If you really want to test the response, you'll need an integration test, not a unit test."

In practice I have to test the response status only when there is the chance to return something else than 200.. and in that case I will use the ResponseEntity as returned type from the controller, which will allow me to test it.